# Drush Make error "No Core Project specified"

Tags: drupal-7, drush

I am not familiar with drush. I am creating an installation profile using drush. I have used the "profiler builder" module in drupal 7 and got a drupal-org.make file.
Now when I execute drush make drupal-org.make file, drush throws an error 'No Core Project specified'. 
Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a "core" module in your drush-makefile, especially if you use custom distribution:

```
core = 7.x
api = 2

projects[l10n_install][type] = core
projects[l10n_install][version] = 1.0
```

If you do not specifiy `projects[...][type] = core`, then drush make uses the most recent default drupal distribution.

You can use the option "-v" or "-d" to debug the running drush command.

Here ist a good introduction into drush-make: http://www.lullabot.com/blog/articles/drush-make-and-pressflow

Please provide the drush-make file, if you need more assistance.